# PHP returns floats instead of strings from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, base-conversion, unique-id

I use this to create a unique code for each product in my store,

```
echo base_convert(uniqid(),16,10);
```

For instance,

```
1403802682572650
```

My query is simple like this,

```
        $sql = "
            SELECT * 
            FROM page AS p

            LEFT JOIN stock AS o
            ON o.id = p.page_id

            WHERE p.type = ?
            AND p.hide != ?
            ORDER BY p.backdated_on
        ";
```

And when I want to get the product code, I do this,

```
var_dump($product->code);
```

But PHP returns `float(1.4038026825726E+15)`  instead of `1403802682572650`

Why does PHP returns `float` instead of `string`? How can I get the number as it is?

Or should I convert/cast the number to string or varchar in my SQL query before requesting result from the db table?

**EDIT:**
Found the bug in my code.

I have a line to convert json to array and that convert the string into float, for instance,

```
echo json_decode("1403802682572650", true); // 1.4038026825726E+15
```

Comment: What is data type of code table field?

Comment: `varchar(255) utf8_general_ci` so it should be just fine right?

Comment: The number is too big: php > echo 1403804750765990; // 1.403804750766E+15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is out of range.

**PHP Man:**

The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

Comment: Out of range for a string? Don't think so.

Comment: Somehow, it was converted to int and then interpreted as float. I guess it happens in your DB object.

Comment: Yea, it must be caused by something else!

Comment: found the bug, please see my edit above - `echo json_decode("1403802682572650", true); // 1.4038026825726E+15`

Comment: Obviously, you don't need to decode string which is not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should change the column itself to `VARCHAR` since it's not *really* being used as a number.

Comment: the db table column is set to be `varchar(255) utf8_general_ci` and I can't see where the error is...

Comment: Verify that the data wasn't fried on the way in then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things without making possibly harmful changes to the database schema.

You can first type cast $product->code:

```
var_dump( (string) $product->code );
```

Or you can cast/convert the select in the query:

```
SELECT CAST(columnName as char) as code ...
```

I've always been a fan of handling most changes like this via the code rather than the query, in the event that a database engine doesn't support your query.

Comment: thanks. I tried to cast the select in the query but I still get the number as a float - `1.403804750766E+15`....

Comment: I'm using PHP PDO and this line may be causing this issue, - `$this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Comment: found the bug in my script. it is caused by `json_decode`. thanks for the help.